# Как записать новое значение?

Tags: javascript

Как мне записывать новое значение переменной oB? Чтобы каждую секунду оно обновлялось

```js
function opacityApp(){
    let oB = 0;
    let newInt = setInterval(opacityButton, 1000);
    function opacityButton(){
        if(oB == 1){
            clearInterval(newInt);
        } else {
            oB + 0.1;
            console.log(oB);
            buttonApp[0].style.opacity = oB;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Вот так `oB += 0.1;`